# How to change the text color in object tags?

Tags: html, object, colors

Hello friends,
              I am trying to change the text colors as red which i am reading from another text file (i.e lastupdate.txt)  in order to print the text in the bottom of my html page, i am not able to get the output, here i am showing my minimal code in hmtl, color.html file is shown below

```
<html>
<body>
<nav id="bottomnav"><center> <font color="red"><object  width="599" height="200" data="lastupdate.txt"></object></font>   </center></nav>
</body>
</html>
```

My lastupdate.txt is contained some text as shown below

```
Last updated on:25th May, 2019
```